# The terminal object comes for free in the definition of a subobject classifier

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

This is Fact 1.4 in [Tom Leinster's informal introduction to topos theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.5647). It states the following: if there exists a mono $t:T \hookrightarrow \Omega$ that classifies the monos in our category, in the sense that for any mono $A \hookrightarrow X$ there exists a unique pullback square $(A \to T \hookrightarrow \Omega) = (A \hookrightarrow X \to \Omega)$, then the object $T$ is necessarily terminal.

I see how to construct a morphism from any object $Y$ to $T;$ namely, the identity $Y \to Y$ is a mono and so induces a morphism $Y \to T$ sitting inside a pullback square. However, I don't see how to use the extra information to conclude that this is the only morphism from $Y$ to $T.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, there is a morphism $f : Y \to T$ making the following diagram a pullback square,
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Y @>{f}>> T \\
@| @VV{t}V \\
Y @>>{t \circ f}> \Omega
\end{CD}$$
and $f : Y \to T$ is the unique morphism with this property (because $t : T \to \Omega$ is a monomorphism). So we need to show that, for any morphism $g : Y \to T$, we have $f = g$. But it is straightforward to check that
$$\begin{CD}
Y @>{g}>> T \\
@| @VV{t}V \\
Y @>>{t \circ g}> \Omega
\end{CD}$$
is always a pullback square, so indeed $f = g$.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure: the fact that the bottom square is a pullback square depends on the fact that $t$ is a mono, correct?

Comment: Yes, it does use the fact that $t$ is a monomorphism.